# ADF Task flow not not displaying data

Tags: jsf, loading, oracle-adf

From *Task flow 1* I go to *Task flow 2*, where I have a view with a table in it. When I edit the table or just skipping the view I have a button which leads me to *Task flow 1*. When I go to *Task flow 2* again I do not see the table although I have a binding. Do you have any assumption about the problem?
[image]

Comment: Can you see the contents of tf2 if you just dragged it into a JSF page?